# Is it possible to import multiple files with a loop in python?

Tags: python, import

In a project I'm working on, I need to import many files whose name are quite similar.

```
from TCA1 import TCA1
from TCA2 import TCA2
from TCA3 import TCA3
from TCA4 import TCA4
.
.
.
from TCA15 import TCA15
```

So I wonder about the possibility of putting all of these imports in a loop.

I know its ridiculous but something like:

```
list = ["TCA1","TCA2","TCA3"...,"TCA15"]

for lib in list:
    from lib import lib
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the names beforehand, just write the imports. Keep it clear.

Comment: What are these things you're importing? It sounds like they may be data files, in which case you may not want to use the import mechanism for this.

Comment: True, they are test cases including data. So I must import them..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
import importlib

module_list = ["TCA1","TCA2","TCA3","TCA15"]

g = globals()
for lib in module_list:
    g[lib] = importlib.import_module('{0}.{0}'.format(lib))
```

**NOTE** If there's `g` in the `module_list`, this will not work. You should choose other name in such case.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like that is equivalent to ```from pkg import item as name``` using ```importlib``` ?

Comment: @Broxigar, `name = importlib.import_module(/pkg.item')`, By asssinging to the name you want :)

Comment: By running the aforemention statement as: ```name = importlib.import_module("folder_name.package.array1")``` I get the error *not a package*

Comment: @Broxigar, If folder_name is not a package, specify `package.array1`. BTW, `folder_name` should be in `sys.path`.

Comment: @Broxigar, For more question, please post a separate question with concrete example (+ directory/file structure), so that others (not just me) can answer you.